# How to select unique records by ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

When I perform "SELECT * FROM table" I got results like below:

```
 ID    Date         Time        Type
 ----------------------------------
 60    03/03/2013   8:55:00 AM   1                      
 60    03/03/2013   2:10:00 PM   2                                                  
 110   17/03/2013   9:15:00 AM   1                          
 67    24/03/2013   9:00:00 AM   1                          
 67    24/03/2013   3:05:00 PM   2
```

as you see each ID has a transaction Type 1 and 2 in the same Date
except ID 110 HAS only Type 1

So how could I just get result like this:

```
ID   Date        Time        Type
----------------------------------
110  17/03/2013  9:15:00 AM  1
```

as only one record are returned from the first result

Comment: Can it be assumed that, if there is only one record for a specific ID, it will be of type 1?

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one transaction for a specific ID and date, all with the same Type? For example, could ID=110 have TWO transactions with Type=1 on the same date? If that is possible, what is the desired result? (NOTE: Something like that is possible, for example, if Type=1 means "login" and Type=2 means "logout" - someone can log in again. So the answer to my question depends on YOUR application.)

Answer (score 2):

Change the partition definition (`partition by id,date`) according to your needs

```
select  *

from   (select  t.*
               ,count(*) over (partition by id,date) as cnt
        from    mytable t
        ) t

where   t.cnt = 1
;
```

Comment: This checks that there is one record, but says nothing about the type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the answer is defined by the question. I don't like to guess what is the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select * from my_table t
where exists (
select 1 from my_table
where id = t.id
group by id
having count(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only type 1, then compare the  minimum and maximum values.  I prefer window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(type) over (partition by id) as mintype,
             max(type) over (partition by id) as maxtype
     from t
    ) t
where mintype = maxtype and mintype = 1;
```

If you want only records of the same type (and not specifically `type = 1`), then remove that condition.

If you want only records on the same day, then include the date in the `partition by`.

Under some circumstances, `not exists` can be faster:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.type <> 1);
```

Comment: `not exist` won't be faster. These analytics functions do not require sort.

Comment: What about records with NULL type? both your queries won't detect it... :-)

Comment: `not exists` should be faster with the proper index when there are many rows per `id`.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The OP explicitly states "as you see each ID has a transaction Type 1 and 2".  I take that to mean that the `Type` only has these values.  The OP does not state that there is only one row per id with a given type.

Comment: The OP said that as regard to the data sample. As I said, I am not a big fan of the "guess what is my real data looks like" game.

Comment: P.s. The OP doesn't even say that he wants only rows with type 1, it can be any type as well.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I don't know if English is your first language, but to me, the OP is clearly asking for ids that only have type 1:  "HAS only Type 1".  The OP says nothing about the number of rows on a given day.  Or about other types.  The question doesn't sort of imply that the values are for the same day, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: Gordon - you can't always assume that the OP's first language is English, either! :-) I agree with Dudu on the fundamental thing (why guess?); I know you don't agree in most cases.

Comment: No it is not, but still I think the question is not well defined. The OP only describes this specific example.